# $A^{-1}$ in the Triangular factorisation of a MA(1) process

Tags: time-series, moving-average

I am trying to confirm the what the $A^{-1}$ actually is in a triangular factorisation of the variance-covariance of a MA(1) process. And what I have found doesn't seem to match what is on Hamilton p.129 (Time Series Analysis (Hamilton, 1994)). Does anyone know which is correct?

On Hamilton p.129, the variance-covariance matrix of a MA(1) process can be decomposed using the triangular factorisation thusly:

$\Omega = ADA'$

$
\hspace{2mm}\text{where $A$ is given by}$
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{\theta}{1+{\theta}^2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{{\theta}(1+{\theta}^2)}{1+{\theta}^2+{\theta}^4} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{{\theta}(1+{\theta}^2 +{\theta}^4+...+{\theta}^{2(t-2)})}{1+{\theta}^2 +{\theta}^4+...+{\theta}^{2(t-1)}} & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

therefore we can construct an auxiliary time series thusly

$\widetilde{y} = A^{-1}(y-\mu) $

$$\text{where}\hspace{5mm} \widetilde{y_t} = y_t - \mu - [\frac{{\theta}(1+{\theta}^2 +{\theta}^4+...+{\theta}^{2(t-2)})}{1+{\theta}^2 +{\theta}^4+...+{\theta}^{2(t-1)}}]\widetilde{y}_{t-1}
$$

this implies the $A^{-1}$ being:

$$ A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{-\theta}{1+{\theta}^2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{-{\theta}(1+{\theta}^2)}{1+{\theta}^2+{\theta}^4} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-{\theta}(1+{\theta}^2 +{\theta}^4+...+{\theta}^{2(t-2)})}{1+{\theta}^2 +{\theta}^4+...+{\theta}^{2(t-1)}} & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

However, when I tried to inverse the same A matrix using the [SymbolLab calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/inverse%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%260%260%260%5C%5C%20%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7B1%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%7D%261%260%260%5C%5C%20%200%26%5Cfrac%7Ba%5Cleft(1%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)%7D%7B1%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%2Ba%5E%7B4%7D%7D%261%260%5C%5C%20%200%260%26%5Cfrac%7Ba%5Cleft(1%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%2Ba%5E%7B4%7D%5Cright)%7D%7B1%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%2Ba%5E%7B4%7D%2Ba%5E%7B6%7D%7D%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D?or=input) I got this

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{-\theta}{1+{\theta}^2} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{{\theta}^2}{1+{\theta}^2+{\theta}^4} & \frac{-{\theta}(1+{\theta}^2)}{1+{\theta}^2+{\theta}^4} & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{-\theta^3}{1+{\theta}^2+{\theta}^4+{\theta}^6} & \frac{\theta^2}{\theta^4+1} & \frac{-{\theta}({\theta}^4+{\theta}^2+1)}{1+{\theta}^2+{\theta}^4+{\theta}^6} & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Does anyone know which is actually correct?

Comment: $A=I+N$ is the sum of the identity matrix $I$ and a *nilpotent* matrix $N.$  Moreover, $N$ is in a canonical form whereby $N^j$ has nonzero values along a single diagonal for every $j.$ Thus (by the Binomial Theorem) $A^{-1}=1-N+N^2-N^3+\cdots + (-1)^{t-1}N^{t-1}.$ You can recognize that pattern in the calculator's value.  Regardless, the standard way to verify a matrix inverse is to perform the multiplication $AA^{-1}$ or $A^{-1}A$ (whichever looks simpler).  Which answer yields the identity matrix?

Comment: But that would imply Hamilton is wrong. How does one calculate an VC Matrix of a MA(1) process using exact likelihood otherwise? Is there a textbook on this?

Comment: Also why is this off topic? Does this forum not accept question regarding proof of time series?

Comment: This is purely a linear algebra question.  It's not about time series.  Indeed, it's a misreading of Hamilton: he gives a *triangular factorization,* not an inverse.  As such it's even *less* about time series.